# Snake.cpp isn't in Fuerte?

Tags: opencv, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Why there isn't the function snake in opencv installed by default by ROS Fuerte? I saw the function does exist when you install opencv from the opencv.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49182/snake.cpp-isn%27t-in-fuerte?/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting in Fuerte, OpenCV is not a ros package but a system dependancy. Double check which version of opencv you installed for ros and which version has snake. Also look around answers.ros.org, there might be a solution for you.

Similar question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33543/opencv-240-vs-231-ros-fuerte/).

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2012-11-28**:
Ok, for what I understand ROS Fuerte has version 2.3.1, I was looking at version 2.4.0 ... But how can I implement that function, or how can I update my OpenCV version from Fuerte ... I have installed OpenCV 2.4.0 in Ubuntu 11.10 but my system uses OpenCV from Fuerte by default

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-10**:
You can't easily switch it.  If you want to you need to check everything that builds on top of it out from source.